# Java test bridge for Automation testing in TFS 2015

Tags: java, tfs-2015, jtest

Using **JTest Automation Association extension-** I want to test dotnet webapp with selenium Java Scripts. Agenda is to do continuous integration in TFS.(Build+Test through selenium scripts in Java together in TFS)

I have dotnet project app repository in TFS and Test scripts in Eclipse.
I know that we need to create JSON mapping file, to test with this extension, which maps each Test case to Test plan work Item id in TFS.

But where to put this JSON file?
and where to put my Java tests (location) so that JSON can read and execute these when build is triggered. 
Also, how to add this extension as a step in build workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you use [Advanced JTest Automation Association](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlmaToolBoxCE.JavaTestBridgeForTestPlan) extension?

On the extension website, it has indicates this task must be executed after a **Maven build** and expects the test results to be in the form **TEST-ClassName.MethodName.xml**.

> You can create a JSON file that must map each java test with a test
>   plan workitem (ID) and add to the source directory or you can provide
>   the JSON string as input (escaped) argument.

Having such an extension allows us to achieve the intended ideal flow:

1. The developer prepares the tests and commits the code.
2. The tester/reviewer creates a test plan, and then creates a JSON
   file that maps 1:1 each Java test with a test plan work item (by
   using the ID).
3. Apache Maven is used to compile and test the Java solution.
4. This extension is added as a step in the build workflow.
5. The test plan is executed.
6. The Java test results are automatically consolidated within the test
   plan.

You could refer to the blog below to get more information:

https://microsoft.github.io/techcasestudies/devops/2017/05/22/Almaviva.html